# Delete line from 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm have a 585L, 2L numpy array in Python.
The data is organized like in this example.

```
0,0
1,0
2,1
3,0
4,0
5,1
...
```

I would like to create an array deleting all the lines where 0 is present on the seconds column. Thus, the final result pretended is:

```
2,1
5,1
```

I have read some related examples but I'm still struggling with this.

Comment: How are you declaring the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention your structure being a numpy array, rather than a list, I would use numpy logical indexing to select only the values you care for.

```python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = [[0,0], [1,0], [2,1], [3,0], [4,0], [5,1]] # Create dummy list
>>> x = np.asarray(x) # Convert list to numpy array
>>> x[x[:, 1] != 0] # Select out items whose second column don't contain zeroes

 array([[2, 1],
   [5, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer
if your list like this [[0,0],[2,1],[4,3],[2,0]]
if your list structure isnt like this please tell me

my answer prints the list whose second column num dont equal to  0

```
    print [x for x in your_list if x[1] != 0] #your_list is the variable of the list
```

Comment: Thank you also. Similar to @SimeonJM, I just replaced the != to ==

Answer (score 0):

You could use an list comprehension. These are described on the Python Data Structures page ([Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)).

If your array is:

```
x = [[0,0],
    [1,0],
    [2,1],
    [3,0],
    [4,0],
    [5,1]]
```

Then the following command

```
[y for y in x if y[1] != 0]
```

Would return the desired result of:

```
[[2, 1], [5, 1]]
```

Edit: I overlooked that it was a numpy array. Taking that into account, JoErNanO's answer is better.

Comment: Yes exactly what needed. I was trying to do something similar but my proposed array comprehension was messed up. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. JoErNanO's solution is more efficient for a numpy array, though, I believe.

Comment: Ok, in this cased I marked solved by @JoErNanO solution. Thank you both.